# Woocommerce order_complete email dont send after changing order status via sql

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, order, sql

I wrote a program that automatically fullfills my orders from woocommerce. After having fullfilled the order I changed the order_status from the order to "wc-completed" via sql.

Everything works fine but the email which should be send when an order is completed is not send. Do you have any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your answers,
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

If you make the changes directly through SQL you won't trigger the order change event and that's why the email is not being sent.

Instead of changing order via SQL you need to use some predefined function like update_status :

```
$ord = new WC_Order($ID); //ID of the order
$ord->update_status('completed')
```

Comment: Hey, that makes sense, thank you! To be honest, I am new in coding with php. I wanted to create a php file which turn the order_status of a special order (for example 108) to 'completed'. As I opened the page there was always an error like: class WC_Order not found. How can I use the predefined functions from Woocommerce in external php file? Greetings, Philipp

Comment: @PhilippRitter in order to use such function you need to include the necessary files .... but i think it's gonna be a bit difficult to do from an external file. As you need to include both Woocommerce files and WP files which means you need to be on the site